# Is the adjoint of an isometry $S$ the inverse of $S$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators, isometry

> Let $S$ be an isometry with adjoint $S^\ast$. Prove that $S^\ast S=SS^\ast=I$.

Here is what I have so far:

Since $S$ is isometry, there is an orthonormal basis of $e_j$'s such that $\|Se_j\|=\|e_j\|$.

Then $\langle e_j,e_k\rangle=\langle Se_j,Se_k\rangle=\langle e_j,S^\ast Se_k\rangle$ which implies that $S^\ast Se_j=e_j$ whch means $S^\ast S=I$.

How do I prove that $SS^\ast =I$ as well though?

Comment: More to the point, every invertible matrix commutes with its inverse.

Comment: The existence of a right inverse would be automatic if you are in a finite dimensional space. In this case being isometric is the same as being unitary. If S is isometric, then $\langle Sv, Sv\rangle = \langle v, v \rangle$. Show that this implies $\langle Bv, v\rangle = 0$ for all $v$, where $B= S^{*}S - I$, which is a self-adjoint operator. Show $\langle Bv,u \rangle + \langle Bu, v\rangle =0$. Use that B is self-adjoint and to rewrite this equation as twice the real part of something equal zero. Plug in $iu$ to conclude $\langle Bv, u \rangle =0$ for all $v,u$. This shows $Bv = v$.